# Add the doubles read from a text file

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I'm almost done with my project but I need some help. I need to add the Hours Overtime and Hours Worked (e.g. the output for Hours Overtime would be 7 because only two people worked ovvertime.) but I do not know how to proceed. Here is the code:

```
static final double OVERTIME_RATE = 1.5; 
static final double FULL_TIME = 40.0; 
static double totalGrossAmount;
static double grossAmount;
static double hourlyRate; 
static double hoursWorked;
static double hoursOT;
static double totalHoursOT;
static StringBuffer employeeName;


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException { 

    reportOverlay(); 
    makeFile();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("Employee.dat")); 

    while(scan.hasNextLine()) { 

        employeeName = new StringBuffer(scan.nextLine()); 
        hoursWorked = new Double(scan.nextDouble());
        hoursOT = new Double(scan.nextDouble());
        hourlyRate = new Double(scan.nextDouble()); 

        scan.nextLine(); 

        double[] pay = processPay(hoursWorked, hoursOT, hourlyRate);

        printEmployeeInfo(employeeName, hoursWorked, hoursOT, hourlyRate,
                          pay[0]); 
    } 

    scan.close(); 
    totalAmounts(); 
} 

static void reportOverlay() { 

    String reportStr = "Employee             Hours    Hours     Pay      Amount     \n" 
                     + "Name                 Worked   Overtime  Rate     Earned    \n" 
        + "-------------------- -------- --------- -------- --------\n"; 

    System.out.print(reportStr); 
} 

static double[] processPay(double hoursWorked, double hoursOT, double payRate ) { 


    grossAmount = 0;                   // <*********
    if(hoursWorked > FULL_TIME)
    {
        grossAmount = (payRate * FULL_TIME) +
                      (payRate * OVERTIME_RATE * (hoursWorked - FULL_TIME));
    }   
    else 
        grossAmount = payRate * hoursWorked; 

    totalGrossAmount = totalGrossAmount + grossAmount;  
    return new double[] {grossAmount};
} 

static void printEmployeeInfo(StringBuffer employeeName, double hoursWorked,
                              double hoursOT, double payRate,
                              double gross) 
{            // <*********
    System.out.printf("%-20s %8.2f %9.2f %8.2f %8.2f%n", employeeName,
                      hoursWorked, hoursOT, payRate, gross); // <*********
} 

static void totalAmounts() { 

    System.out.printf("Total %51.2f%n", totalGrossAmount); 
    System.out.println(); 
} 

static void makeFile() throws FileNotFoundException { 

    PrintWriter printF = new PrintWriter("Employee.dat"); 

    printF.write("Bugs Bunny\n40 0 15.25\nRoad Runner\n35 0 15.35\n"
                +"Wild E. Coyote\n45 5 16.00\nDaffy Duck\n42 2 15.75\n"); 
    printF.close(); 
} 

/*static void totalHours() {

    totalHoursOT = hoursWorked - FULL_TIME;
        if (totalHoursOT < 0)
        {


}
```

Here is what the output should look like:

```
Employee             Hours    Hours     Pay      Amount      
Name                 Worked   Overtime  Rate     Earned     
-------------------- -------- --------- -------- --------
Bugs Bunny              40.00      0.00    15.25   610.00
Road Runner             35.00      0.00    15.35   537.25
Wild E. Coyote          45.00      5.00    16.00   760.00
Daffy Duck              42.00      2.00    15.75   677.25
Total                   162        7              2584.50
```

Here is what it is right now because I don't know how to add the hours:

```
 Employee             Hours    Hours     Pay      Amount      
Name                 Worked   Overtime  Rate     Earned     
-------------------- -------- --------- -------- --------
Bugs Bunny              40.00      0.00    15.25   610.00
Road Runner             35.00      0.00    15.35   537.25
Wild E. Coyote          45.00      5.00    16.00   760.00
Daffy Duck              42.00      2.00    15.75   677.25
Total                                             2584.50
```

Comment: Calculate the hours worked and hours overtime the same way you're calculating the amount earned. You're on the right track.

Comment: To match the output you will probably want to cast  your overtime total and hours worked total to an int.

Comment: @MikeKoch How would I proceed though? I have been working on this for about 6 hours now so I'm kind of burned out... Can you go in detail a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: @BigT Yeah, I have to go fix that but I wanted to get it working first.

Comment: @user3606035: You already have `grossAmount = 0`.  Create another variable for `hoursOvertime`.  Then, look at your one conditional, which is `hoursWorked > FULL_TIME`. Since that's overtime, figure out how many hours they worked - FULL_TIME, and add that to your variable `hoursOvertime`.

Comment: @MikeKoch Oh, right. I'm so tired I forgot I even did that. Thank you! Can't believe I didn't catch that.

Comment: @user3606035. No problem. I went ahead and posted it as a community wiki as the answer has been resolved here in the comments.

Comment: @MikeKoch Hey, I ran into a problem. When I try to do that, I get hoursOvertime = 2 so I'm guessing it only adds Duck's Overtime and not Coyote's. Here's what I did. Is it a logic error?

`grossAmount = 0;
hoursOvertime = 0;  // <*********
if(hoursWorked > FULL_TIME)
{
grossAmount = (payRate * FULL_TIME) +
                          (payRate * OVERTIME_RATE * (hoursWorked - FULL_TIME));
      hoursOvertime = hoursWorked - FULL_TIME;
  } 
        else 
  {
            grossAmount = payRate * hoursWorked;
   hoursOvertime = 0;   
  }
  
  hoursOvertime = hoursOvertime + hoursOT;`

Comment: @user3606035 make `hoursOvertime = hoursWorked - FULL_TIME` --> `hoursOvertime += hoursWorked - FULL_TIME`.  Right now you're just setting `hoursOvertime` to how many hours the last person had, not a total

Comment: @MikeKoch Thank you very much. I came back to say I got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have `grossAmount = 0`, so you can do the same thing for calculating overtime hours.  Since you already have a conditional, simple add the overtime hours to your "new" variable (such as `hoursOvertime`).